# Print Byte Array Vertically in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, printf

I have 4 byte arrays containing 4 bytes each, and when I print them they print horizontally, but I need them to print vertically. Is this possible in C? I know when I use `printf()` and pass it the array, it prints all four bytes automatically. Can I sub-divide the array into four separate bytes like a normal array and print each byte on a separate line? There has to be a way.

To illustrate what I am doing, here is the segment that I am having trouble with:

```
    byte a0 = state[0];
    byte a1 = state[1];
    byte a2 = state[2];
    byte a3 = state[3];
    state[0] = lookup_g2[a0] ^ lookup_g3[a1] ^ a2 ^ a3;
    state[1] = lookup_g2[a1] ^ lookup_g3[a2] ^ a3 ^ a0;
    state[2] = lookup_g2[a2] ^ lookup_g3[a3] ^ a0 ^ a1;
    state[3] = lookup_g2[a3] ^ lookup_g3[a0] ^ a1 ^ a2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%02x", state[i]);
    }
    printf("%s", "\n");
```

This prints each byte array in its entirety on each line until `main()`ends. Preferably, I would like to print each array in groups of four vertically.

Also, I know there is `sprintf()` which I was recommended to use but for now I'm using `printf()` until I can figure out how to print vertically.

Example:

```
printf("%02x", state[0]);
```

yields:

```
b9 e4 47 c5
```

The output I am looking for is:

```
b9
e4
47
c5
```

and then the following iterations will print their values next to the first column as shown above. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but put a `\n` at the end of your format string.

Comment: I've tried that. It just moves the next byte array to the next line...

Comment: Perhaps we have a terminology problem. `state[0]` is a single byte. `state[0..3]` is an array. You are printing 4 bytes in a row as 2 hex digits each, not 4 arrays.  Please edit your question with some real values that shows exactly the output you are looking for.

Comment: Isn't `printf("%s", "\n");` the same as `putchar ('\n');`? The suggestion is `printf("%02x\n", state[i]);`

Comment: Then how do you print the next line of bytes in a column next to the first up to four columns then move to a new line?

Comment: Your explanation is still terrible since it does not show 4 rows and columns, but I think this is what you want. You'll have to figure out how to apply it to your situation. https://ideone.com/DcZdYS Your code also doesn't give the output you state it does, there would be no spaces between the values.

Comment: Well, you have 4-byte arrays and do `printf ("%02x %02x %02x %02x\n", a1[i], a2[i], a3[i], a4[i]);` or you do what you are doing, but wrap it in another loop so you print 4 times before outputting the `'\n'`.

Answer (score 1):

> Then how do you print the next line of bytes in a column next to the
>   first up to four columns then move to a new line?

If I follow what you are attempting to do, you have 4 `state` arrays (or 4 rows and columns of something) and you want to output the first line with the first element of each (one in each column), the next line (one element in each column), and so on. If you want to output each value individually, then you will need nested loops, outputting one value at a time in the inner loop (printing each element in a column), then output the `'\n'` once the inner loop completes.

Something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char byte;

int main (void) {

    byte state[] = { 0xb9, 0xe4, 0x47, 0xc5 },
        n = sizeof state / sizeof *state;

    for (byte i = 0; i < n; i++) {              /* outer loop */
        for (byte j = 0; j < n; j++)            /* inner loop */
            printf (" %02x", state[(j+i)%n]);   /* stuff      */
        putchar ('\n'); /* newline after inner loop completes */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/byteperline
 b9 e4 47 c5
 e4 47 c5 b9
 47 c5 b9 e4
 c5 b9 e4 47
```

**note:** I just used the values from the first array 4-times to construct the four columns. You will adjust your *indexing scheme* to whatever is called for by your data (e.g. to print rows as columns or columns as rows) Regardless how you do it, you must output the values in a *row-wise* manner. You can't print a column and then back up 4-lines and offset by 5 chars and print the next column. (I mean you can, but that is well-beyond your question and would require a separate curses library to do in a portable fashion)

Look things over and let me know if this is what you intended.